# Inbound and Outbound Email Flow Issue on PostFix

Tags: postfix, email-server

**Our Setup and Requirement:**

1. Lets say abc.com is hosted on a Email Service Provider
2. We have setup a postfix server for the same domain
3. We would like to route the inbound emails for certain emails to postfix server while others will be delivered on the server hosted by the Email service provider
4. For Outbound email, we are using a SMTP relay on the PostFix Server
5. We already have the routing policy to route certain email address inbound emails to postfix server

**Challenges**

1. We are able to receive emails in postfix server when we have following parameters set in main.confg for PostFix

   *mydestination = localhost*

   *virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysqldb-vdomains.cf*

   *virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysqldb-vusers.cf*

   *virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysqldb-valias.cf*

But the outbound emails doesn't work for the same domain abc.com but it works fine for outbound emails to other domains
2) When we comment off the above parameter for *"virtual.."*, the outbound emails works for same domain, but we don't receive any inbound emails.

Required assistance on a urgent basis.
Thank you.

Comment: Well, any suggestions?

Comment: Any suggestions?